# How to strip png images using ImageMagick?

Tags: imagemagick, png, interlacing

```
convert -strip -interlace JPEG -quality 80 origi.jpg output-file.jpg
```

origi image size : 40.6 kb
output-file image size : 11.3 kb

But if I convert one png file as

```
convert -strip -interlace PNG -quality 80 he.png output-file.png
```

he.png image size : 711 kb
output-file image size : 1 mb

```
convert -strip -interlace PNG he.png output-file.png
```

he.png image size : 711 kb
output-file image size : 972.3 kb

Why the file size has been increased in case of PNG after conversion to output-file.png?

Am I using correct parameters for png conversions?

Comment: What happens if you convert output-file.png into another image? It could be your input and output png images are of a different type. Also your input image should come straight after convert.

Answer (score 2):

If you convert a regular PNG image into an interlaced one, the resulting filesize will probably be larger, as explained in the [PNG specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/#8InterlaceIntro) (emphasis added):

> Pass extraction ... splits a PNG image into a sequence of
>   reduced images (the interlaced PNG image) where the first image
>   defines a coarse view and subsequent images enhance this coarse view
>   until the last image completes the PNG image. This allows progressive
>   display of the interlaced PNG image by the decoder and allows images
>   to "fade in" when they are being displayed on-the-fly. **On average,
>   interlacing slightly expands the datastream size**, but it can give the
>   user a meaningful display much more rapidly.

The "-quality 80" option was not helpful because that forced ImageMagick to not use "filtering" to improve compression.